# best way to bind/trigger events

Tags: jquery

In a single paged application, would this be the best way to bind and trigger events? A websocket connects to the server and initializes, then it calls the page load function etc.

```
var app  = {};
websocket.init(function()
{
   //websocket is loaded, call page load function
   $(app).trigger('load');
});
function logout()
{
  websocket.logout(function()
  {
     //now logged out
     $(app).trigger('loggedout');
  }
}

//page.js
$(app).bind('load', function()
{

});
$(app).bind('loggedout', function()
{

});
```

Comment: The approach seems fine but you should use the more recent jQuery.on() and jQuery.off() methods from the jQuery API

Comment: I think you would just use $.bind('customevent') and $.trigger('customevent'), I'm not sure why you would be turning your app object into a jQuery object...

Comment: If I didn't turn it into a jquery object, how would I bind events to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var app  = {};
websocket.init(function()
{
   //websocket is loaded, call page load function
   $(app).load();
});
function logout()
{
  websocket.logout(function()
  {
     //now logged out
     $(app).loggedout();
  }
}

//page.js
$(app).load(function()
{

});
$(app).loggedout(function()
{

});
```